# Mongo: lock a single document for READ and subsequent update

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo Collection where I store my documents. Each document has a field **complexNestedObject** which, as the name suggests, contains a complex nested object.
I have to create a function that implements the following logic

```
updateComplexNestedObject(_id, data) {
  1) read the document using _id as key
  2) perform some logic based on input data and the content of the document
  3) based on this logic determine the new value of complexNestedObject
  4) update complexNestedObject with the new value
}
```

This function can be invoked concurrently by different clients for the same document **_id** but with different input **data**, so I need to implement some locking mechanism. 
Which is the best locking mechanism? Shall I use Mongo 4 transactional support or is it better some applicative solution?